# XTEST extension unavailable (XQuartz)

Tags: applescript, x11

I am trying to use certain properties of X11 on mac via XQuartz. I am not trying to connect to a remote machine via ssh.

Here is what I am trying to execute

```
bash-3.2$ xdotool cmd+v
Warning: XTEST extension unavailable on '(null)'. Some functionality may be disabled;  See 'man xdotool' for more info.
xdotool: Unknown command: cmd+v
```

I read online and  it mentioned that it helpful to run

```
bash-3.2$ xdpyinfo | grep XTEST
```

but I I got no response to that command.

Also it might be usefull that

```
bash-3.2$ echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.hSfxDpYG4N/org.xquartz:0
```

**Question:** How can I fix this behaviour?

**NB:** I wasn't sure how to tag this post. If anybody has more appropriate tags please let me know.